# Problem reading from boost basic_streambuf with an istream

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm having some problems reading from a streambuf which is being filled through an asyc_read(). When stepping through my code in VS i can see that the correct data is in the buffer but when i go to read it with:

```
std::istream is = std::istream(&buffer_);

unsigned short type;
unsigned short size;

is >> type;
is >> size;
```

The type and size variables remain at their initialized values. No errors or anything are thrown. I'm really stumped as to why this is the case i've seen similar code which reads data off into variables in the exact same way

EDIT:
so here's my async_read code which then calls the above code:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
    buffer_,
    boost::asio::transfer_at_least(4),
    boost::bind(&Session::handleReadBody, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Comment: Hello, dee. Welcome to stack overflow! Would you please post a minimal, complete program that demonstrates the problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `type` remains in its initialized value, it's apparent that `is >> type;` failed: check the status of the stream (`if(is) {...}`) to be sure.

And, seeing as you have a `transfer_at_least(4)`, I suspect that you're transferring binary data, not whitespace-separated strings of ASCII characters. If that is the case, use `read()`:

```
int16_t type, size;
data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&type), sizeof type);
data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof size);
```

but pay attention to byte order.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to fix it. I should have made it clear that i was transferring binary data i didnt know that it made any real difference, i'm pretty new to network programming. idk if there's any easier way to get the data out of the streambuf than just wrapping it in a istream or not

Comment: @dee it makes a difference for reading from a stream (`operator >>` is for whitespace-separated ASCII data, `read()` is for binary). A more direct read from an asio buffer could be with a `reinrepret_cast<const int16_t*>(boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buffer.data()))`